# Convert list of lists to a dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
sample  location    date    spiceis sp.ab
1   001 9/10/2017   sp1 2
1   001 9/10/2017   sp2 5
1   001 9/10/2017   sp3 10
1   001 9/10/2017   sp4 2
2   002 9/11/2017   sp1 0
2   002 9/11/2017   sp2 2
2   002 9/11/2017   sp3 5
2   002 9/11/2017   sp4 5
3   003 9/12/2017   sp1 2
3   003 9/12/2017   sp2 1
3   003 9/12/2017   sp3 1
3   003 9/12/2017   sp4 0
4   004 9/13/2017   sp1 7
4   004 9/13/2017   sp2 4
4   004 9/13/2017   sp3 2
4   004 9/13/2017   sp4 9
```

And i would like to return a dataframe that looks like the following. Can anyone help me with this?

```
sample  location    date    sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1   001 9/10/2017   2   5   10  2
2   002 9/11/2017   0   2   5   5
3   003 9/12/2017   2   1   1   0
4   004 9/13/2017   7   4   2   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each row is a list and by dataframes you mean Pandas dataframes, then you can use list comprehensions to turn the list of lists into a list of tuples:

```
listoftuples = [tuple(l) for l in listoflists]
```

Then use the from_records function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listoftuples,columns=['sample','location','date','spiceis','sp.ab'])
```

Comment: i now have found out that my data was not a list of lists; it was a data frame. when i applied the code, an error occurs: 

AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 8 columns

do you have a modified code for that? 
thank you very much.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question. It seems like you should use pivot_table https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: That's link work for me now. Thank you very much Brine.